# Positioning legend title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to orient the legend title above the legend entries. The default is for the legend title to be left-justified. How do I put it above the legend entries?

```
# reproducible code
library(ggplot2)

n <- 200
data <- data.frame(
   subject = sample(LETTERS[1:5], n, TRUE),
   orientation = sample(c("N","S","E","W"), n, TRUE),
   value = runif(n, 0, 100)
)

ggplot(data) + 
   geom_bar(aes(x = subject, y = value, fill = orientation), stat = "identity") +
   theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

This produces:

[image]

I want the "orientation" title to appear above the legend entries "E", "N", "S", "W". How do I do this?

Comment: Add `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))` to your plot code.

Comment: This is a great first question, user23145573! It has all the needed components: code, sample data, and actual-vs-expected output. Nice!